# Do forced shutdowns cause a laptop's HDD to fail?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I recently bought a new laptop (Acer Aspire E14 (E5-475G-380U)) this last Dec. 2017, it had problems on booting up and i had some numerous "hard resets" on boot time because it was always stuck on the manufacturer logo. And hard resets usually fix it, but sometimes, it does not, and i end up on startup repair. One time, when the startup repair finished, my user profile got corrupted (temporary user login only), and i'm not sure if it is related to the hard drive. I ended up resetting and everything was fine again. I also did a hard reset once on a BSOD error, but it didnt show any "noticeable errors". Not until a few weeks ago. My laptop suddenly displayed a "No Bootable Drive" error while the laptop is running. I checked the BIOS and it does not detect my HDD. i tried these:

1. Shaked the laptop to check if something's loose
2. Applied pressure
3. Few taps on the laptop
4. Checked BIOS

But so far, they did not help. I sent the laptop to the service center and im still waiting for it up until now. My question is, do my hard resets at boot caused my HDD to fail? or is it a problem with the HDD itself? Or is it overuse?

Tasks i'm doing with the laptop that probably damaged the laptop(?):

1. Gaming (usually GTA 5 with mods, running at a bottleneck. CS:GO, and Flight Simulators)
2. Programming (C# and Android Studio)
3. Daily tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to check your hard drive. it seems to be the fault here. hd tune is a good tool but use your manufacturers diagnostic tool. I've seen this many times.

To answer your question, a forced shutdown does not hhd to fail but it could mess with the data on the sectors. For example, maybe Windows is writing things down on some sector and if you shut it down, it could corrupt that part. If thats the case, your windows could become fragile very easily.

try to do the "chkdsk /f /r" command first then see if it gets better. Then use your hard drive diagnostic tool if you can detect your hard drive of course